# Propel / Sybase shows accents as squares

Tags: orm, character-encoding, sybase, propel, latin1

I am using the ORM Propel to interact with my Sybase ASE 15.7 database from a Zend Framework webapp. When I do `sp_helpsort` my Sybase server seems to be using Latin-1 encoding.

I am realising that the accents that are in my database (which shows properly when I connect via a client like Toad for Sybase) show as squares on my web pages. If I pass such data through a JSON object, the string completely disappears and becomes null if it has accents. All the JSON objects are set up with a UTF-8 charset (returned with content-type `application/json;charset=utf-8`).

I tried to fix the issue by changing the character set and sort order of my server to UTF-8 and now `sp_helpsort` clearly shows it is using UTF-8 :

> Sort Order Description
>
> ---
>
> Character Set = 190, utf8
>        Unicode 3.1 UTF-8 Character Set
>        Class 2 Character Set
>    Sort Order = 25, binary
>        Binary ordering for UTF-16
>   (return status = 0)

I tried again, using new data to make sure I don't use former Latin1 encoding text and I still have the same issue.

How can I ensure that the data are recovered properly and won't be affected if I pass them through a JSON object set up with UTF-8?

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. The issue seems to be caused by the driver that I use to connect to my Sybase database : ODBC.
The thing is to tell ODBC that it is using UTF-8 on the client side, so that Sybase can then convert content before returning it, if it uses another character set.

I managed to get the accents to show by adding these parameters to my ODBC connection string: `Charset=utf8;KeepOrgMultibyte=1;`

Sources: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/f3-framework/o5dvvsMCR4c/4-b0ZoSFWKgJ